# Is there a CLI software center that supports reviews and ratings?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

If I can help it, I'd rather not use the GUI, so I don't want to use `gnome-software` when looking for new software, is there some sort of CLI 'software center' which also has the ability to show and submit reviews/ratings (I know about `aptitude` but I don't think it supports them)?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 2):

It's horribly ugly, and not a software center by any means, but if you just want to search for software and see ratings or reviews, try the `w3m` browser on https://apps.ubuntu.com.

Install `w3m` and `w3m-img` (for image support):

```
sudo apt install w3m w3m-img
```

- Nautilus:

  [image: nautilus]
- `lynx-cur`:

  [image]

The package name is given beneath the description, so you can then do `sudo apt install <package-name>`.

I have had some graphics issues with it, but, hey, it works!

---

Among `lynx`, `elinks` and `w3m`, only `w3m` was able to show the stars.

Comment: My experience with w3m, tmux and gnome terminal is that the w3m images don't recognise the tmux panes and spill over into other panes, its probably ok if you just use a plain terminal.

Comment: @the_velour_fog It's horrible enough with just gnome-terminal that I wouldn't dare use it with `tmux` on top :)

Comment: lol, I like using w3m with tmux, mostly for bringing up HTML based documentation in a pane above a terminal I'm doing work in. It uses h,j,k,l for cursor navigation and J, K to scroll text. If you are already familiar with the website its definitely usable!